Cannot connect using RDP and Remmina
I'm New to Ubuntu and need help.
Both machines are Ubuntu 22.04LTS with all current updates. Host has RDP enabled from Settings>System>Remote Desktop. I'm running UFW and status show that appropriate port 3389 is open.
Second system has Remmina 1.4.35. All defaults. But any attempt to connect using Host IP or with :3389 at the end on the IP gives message Cannot connect to the x.x.x.x RDP server.
Any suggestion? Thanks
Edits: It works now?!! Only changes made are to the Host: nethogs installed and ksnip to edit and publish requested info. Where I can look for RDP logs files on the HOST? Very curious why it started to work!
Edit2: One more question: Remmina will not connect until I actually log into the HOST. I cant find how to resolve this. Thank you

Please edit the question to shows us the exact, complete error message.

Have you set up an username and password in the "Remote Desktop" Settings page? Is the remote computer set up to automatically login when it restarts? Edit your question and add all these details and what other commenters ask for.
